# Partition Function and Fibonacci Number

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, integer-partitions

I am asked to prove that $$p(n) < F_n, \qquad n \geq 5$$ where $p(n), \ F_n$ are the number number of partitions of $n$ and the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, respectively.  This is easy if you can show that $$p(n) \leq p(n - 1) + p(n - 2)$$  I am trying to use the recurrence relation for $p(n)$, but haven't been able to show $p(n) \leq p(n - 1) + p(n - 2)$.  Does anyone have any insight for showing this with the recurrence relation?

Comment: Consider the following map. You take a partition of $n,$ if the last part is a $1$ you send it the a partition of $n-1$ and you eliminate the last part. If not, you take out $2$ from the last part. Is this function a bijection? An injection? A surjection?

Comment: If I am thinking about what you are saying correctly it should be an injection into $p(n - 1) \cup p(n - 2)$ @Phicar

Comment: Although, I may be misunderstanding what you are saying

Comment: With what I believe is the standard definition of Fibonacci numbers I think your result should be $p(n)<F_{n+1}$ but you are right re. needing the inequality. I've added an answer for this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts.

If a partition counted in $P_k(n)$ contains no $1$s then subtracting $1$ from every number gives a partition which is counted in $P_k(n-k)$.

If a partition counted in $P_k(n)$ contains at least one $1$ then deleting a $1$  gives a partition which is counted in $P_{k-1}(n-1)$.

Therefore $$P_k(n)= P_k(n-k)+P_{k-1}(n-1).$$
For $k=1$, $P_1(n)= P_1(n-2)=1$ and for $k\ge2$, $P_k(n)\le P_k(n-2)+P_{k-1}(n-1)$.

So, if we sum over all $k$, we obtain $$P(n)\le P(n-2)+P(n-1),$$ as required.